# Python-gitlab API V4

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

Does anyone know if Python-GitLab is still supported?
I am trying to simply print the list of my project from GitLab but it doesn't work.

Example:

```
projects = gl.projects.list()
for project in projects:
    print(project)
```

I tried many things and it doesn't work. Maybe it's not working with gitlab.com?

Any helpful information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be specific as to what you have tried and what errors you're getting.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is no more a problem statement than "Yes it does" is an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I tested python-gitlab today and it still works. This is my sample python file below. I defined "ACCESS_TOKEN" in a .env file in the project. You will need an access token to connect to the Gitlab instance.

```py
import gitlab
import os
from envparse import env

if os.path.isfile('.env'):
    env.read_envfile()

ACCESS_TOKEN = env('ACCESS_TOKEN')

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', ACCESS_TOKEN)


def get_projects():
    projects = gl.projects.list(owned=True)
    for project in projects:
        print(project.name)


def main():
    get_projects()


main()
```